# Changing string to number and summing up digits

Tags: javascript, regex

Here is what I have:

```js
// My globals
var output = $("#output");

function m_o() {
  // var input = $("#input");
//   var value = input.val();
 var value = "SCORE";

  // Setting
  var r_o = {
    // Setting #customizing
    A:  "1",
    B:  "2",
    C:  "3",
    D:  "4",
    E:  "5",
    F:  "6",
    G:  "7",
    H:  "8",
    I:  "9",
    J: "10",
    K: "11",
    L: "12",
    M: "13",
    N: "14",
    O: "15",
    P: "16",
    Q: "17",
    R: "18",
    S: "19",
    T: "20",
    U: "21",
    V: "22",
    W: "23",
    X: "24",
    Y: "25",
    Z: "26",
  };

  // Translating
  var re = new RegExp(Object.keys(r_o).join("|"), "g");

  value = value.replace(re, function (matched) {
    return r_o[matched];
  });

  value = parseInt(value.split("").join(" + "), 10);

  output.val(value);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>5X Script</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <!--<textarea id="input">
   
  </textarea>-->
  <input type="button" value="Translate" onclick="m_o()"/>
  <textarea id="output">
   
  </textarea>
 </body>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.js"></script>
</html>
```

Once you press the *Translate* button, the texarea will display `1`.

That is not what should happen. Our *input* is `SCORE`, so the outcome should be "19+3+15+18+5". In other words, the *output* should be equal to `60`.

Please try to explain it, it's really hard for me to understand this.

Comment: Why so complex? String's `replace` may accept `String` as a parameter, not only `Regexp`.

Comment: @hindmost as I said, I'm just starting, it all seems very confusing for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get `1` as an output because of this [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)'s behavior:

> If `parseInt` encounters a character that is not a numeral in the
>   specified radix, it ignores it and all succeeding characters and
>   returns the integer value parsed up to that point.

What I think you need is to use `eval` and use a `+` before each replacement:

Replace `return r_o[matched];` with `return "+"+r_o[matched];` and use:

```
value = parseInt(eval(value), 10);
```

Or if you are not considering `eval`, here is a custom function:

```
function sumup(s){
    var total= 0, s= s.match(/\+\d+/g) || [];
    while(s.length){
        total+= parseInt(s.shift());
    }
    return total;
}
```

Here is your updated snippet:

```js
// My globals
var output = $("#output");

function sumup(s){
    var total= 0, s= s.match(/\+\d+/g) || [];
    while(s.length){
        total+= parseInt(s.shift());
    }
    return total;
}

function m_o() {
  // var input = $("#input");
//   var value = input.val();
 var value = "SCORE";

  // Setting
  var r_o = {
    // Setting #customizing
    A:  "1",
    B:  "2",
    C:  "3",
    D:  "4",
    E:  "5",
    F:  "6",
    G:  "7",
    H:  "8",
    I:  "9",
    J: "10",
    K: "11",
    L: "12",
    M: "13",
    N: "14",
    O: "15",
    P: "16",
    Q: "17",
    R: "18",
    S: "19",
    T: "20",
    U: "21",
    V: "22",
    W: "23",
    X: "24",
    Y: "25",
    Z: "26",
  };

  // Translating
  var re = new RegExp(Object.keys(r_o).join("|"), "g");

  value = value.replace(re, function (matched) {
    return "+"+r_o[matched];
  });

  value = sumup(value);

  output.val(value);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>5X Script</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <!--<textarea id="input">
   
  </textarea>-->
  <input type="button" value="Translate" onclick="m_o()"/>
  <textarea id="output">
   
  </textarea>
 </body>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: but isn't `eval` considered dangerus?

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid storing `"letter":"number"` mapping, by taking advantage of Ascii values, just convert uppercase and subtract 64

```
function m_o() {
    var value ="SCORE";
    var finalCount = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
        finalCount += (value.toUpperCase().charCodeAt(i) - 64);
    }
    $("#output").html(finalCount);
}
```

click for **[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/x7rwq5zm/2/)**

Comment: Well, I agree, epcept that I will also be doing other digits, including negatives, but +1 for your originality

Answer (score 1):

I feel like you are overcomplicating it. You could just go over each character in the string using a loop.

For each letter, check that it exists in the `r_o` object, and if so, get the corresponding value from the object and add it to the total.

Here is an example

```
 // Translating
  var length = value.length; //how many characters in the string?
  var total = 0;  //what you will return

  for(let i=0; i < value.length; i++) //for each character in the string
  {
     var m = value[i];
     if(r_o.hasOwnProperty(m)) total += r_o[m];
     //if the char is in the obj, add the corresponding value
  }


  output.val(total);  //return the new total
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are doing, could you elaborate?

Comment: @julianavar I added some more text to help guide you.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, parseInt cannot evaluate expressions like you are doing. Anyways, I would suggest to use `String.prototype.charCodeAt` in order to make your code more readable and changing your functions and variables names.

**EDIT:** Just to make the answer more clear: what your are passing to `parseInt` is actually a string that contains an expression like "`1 + 2 + 3 + 4`"...
What `parseInt` is trying to do is just parse the first integer it gets, in this case a `1`. As the other told you, your solution seem really complicate and you should change it, but in case you are really happy with this solution (you shouldn't) you could change:

```
value = parseInt(value.split("").join(" + "), 10);
```

with:

```
eval("value = " + value.split("").join(" + ") + ";");
```

There's actually another mistake in your code: you are doing a `split("")`. This can lead to an error when you replace a character with a 2 digit number, like 19 (this is why even with my solution, you'll get 33 instead of 60). Your RegEx replaces `S` with `19`, but then, when you split and join, your 2 digits number is split in 1 and 9. A simple solution could be to add a whitespace when replacing and then using it to split the values, replacing:

```
return r_o[matched];
```

with

```
return ' ' + r_o[matched];
```

and

```
eval("value = " + value.split("").join(" + ") + ";");
```

with

```
eval("value = " + value.split(" ").join(" + ") + ";");
```

Little explanation: Right now when you do your replacement you are actually replacing a character with `<space><number>`. You then use this space to split correctly the values and then joining them with the `+` operator. Finally, you evaluate the string `"value = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4;`.

**This answer is just for an "educational" purpose, your code should be rewritten**

Working snippet:

```js
// My globals
var output = $("#output");

function m_o() {
  // var input = $("#input");
//   var value = input.val();
 var value = "SCORE";

  // Setting
  var r_o = {
    // Setting #customizing
    A:  "1",
    B:  "2",
    C:  "3",
    D:  "4",
    E:  "5",
    F:  "6",
    G:  "7",
    H:  "8",
    I:  "9",
    J: "10",
    K: "11",
    L: "12",
    M: "13",
    N: "14",
    O: "15",
    P: "16",
    Q: "17",
    R: "18",
    S: "19",
    T: "20",
    U: "21",
    V: "22",
    W: "23",
    X: "24",
    Y: "25",
    Z: "26",
  };

  // Translating
  var re = new RegExp(Object.keys(r_o).join("|"), "g");

  value = value.replace(re, function (matched) {
    return ' ' + r_o[matched];
  });

  eval("value = " + value.split(' ').join(" + ") + ";");

  output.val(value);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>5X Script</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <!--<textarea id="input">
   
  </textarea>-->
  <input type="button" value="Translate" onclick="m_o()"/>
  <textarea id="output">
   
  </textarea>
 </body>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is like this

```
var value = "SCORE";

 // Setting
 var r_o = {
 // Setting #customizing
 A:  "1",
 B:  "2",
 C:  "3",
 D:  "4",
 E:  "5",
 F:  "6",
 G:  "7",
 H:  "8",
 I:  "9",
J: "10",
K: "11",
L: "12",
M: "13",
N: "14",
O: "15",
P: "16",
Q: "17",
R: "18",
S: "19",
T: "20",
U: "21",
V: "22",
W: "23",
X: "24",
Y: "25",
Z: "26",
};

// Translating
var re = new RegExp(Object.keys(r_o).join("|"), "g");
var output =0;


 value.replace(re, function (matched) {
        output += parseInt(r_o[matched]);
});

alert(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically the value `parseInt` "see's" is "1 + ..." and parses 1.

Look at the modified snippet, open your console log, and see what happens.
Take this as an opportunity to learn how to debug.

```js
// My globals
var output = $("#output");

function m_o() {
  // var input = $("#input");
//   var value = input.val();
 var value = "SCORE";

  // Setting
  var r_o = {
    // Setting #customizing
    A:  "1",
    B:  "2",
    C:  "3",
    D:  "4",
    E:  "5",
    F:  "6",
    G:  "7",
    H:  "8",
    I:  "9",
    J: "10",
    K: "11",
    L: "12",
    M: "13",
    N: "14",
    O: "15",
    P: "16",
    Q: "17",
    R: "18",
    S: "19",
    T: "20",
    U: "21",
    V: "22",
    W: "23",
    X: "24",
    Y: "25",
    Z: "26",
  };

  // Translating
  var re = new RegExp(Object.keys(r_o).join("|"), "g");

  value = value.replace(re, function (matched) {
    console.log(matched);
    return r_o[matched];
  });
  console.log(value);
  var t = value.split("").join(" + ");
  console.log('About to "parseInt":', t);
  value = parseInt(t, 10);
  console.log(value);

  output.val(value);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>5X Script</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <!--<textarea id="input">
   
  </textarea>-->
  <input type="button" value="Translate" onclick="m_o()"/>
  <textarea id="output">
   
  </textarea>
 </body>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: I clicked translate I got 1 for answer, when the answer should be 60

Comment: @julianavar - You asked to be explained why you're getting 1, while expecting 60. This explains why (Did you look at the your browser debug console?). I did not attempt to "correct" your code, and I truly believe you'll be much better off if you learn how to debug, and understand how to solve this yourself (not that hard really) rather than being spoon fed.

Comment: Well, yeah, I opened the debugger, I understand what it's doing now, but don't really know how to make it better, and please, don't be unrespectfull to me, I am a 15 year old who just started this, and sorry to seem not nice, but I just don't know what to do.

Comment: I'm not trying to be disrespectful at all. The contrary.. I'm trying to be helpful.. To educate.. To show you how to work your way around a problem. I think that's worth a lot more than having a program that can sum a few numbers.

Comment: Well thank you for careing, sorry to be so defensive. But anyways, I just couldn't understand, and I see your point, and I do see my error, but it's one of those things that although you know your error you don't know how to solve. And I do agree with you, prosses is much better than result.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fairly simple approach:

```
var charVal = function(c) {return c.charCodeAt(0) - 'A'.charCodeAt(0) + 1;};
var add = function(a, b) {return a + b;};
var convert = function(s) {return s.split('').map(charVal).reduce(add, 0);};

convert('SCORE'); //=> 60
```

You might want to do some bounds checking in `charVal` and some null-checking and/or type-checking in `convert`, but this is pretty simple, I think.