# Regexp in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, testing, eval

I want to test a regular expresion like this:
213+123, a number plus + plus a number.
This is de code:

```
var re = /\d+[+]\d+/
result = window.eval(command);
var bool = re.test(result);
```

The code respond false if I try to enter 234+234. Any help

Comment: Your regex is True seems that the problem is because of your functions

Comment: Shouldn't it be `re.test(command)`? If you eval `213+123`, you get back the result of the expression, which is a single number.

Comment: Just a note that using `eval` is not safe with user input. I have written a [`sumup` function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31372109/changing-string-to-number-and-summing-up-digits/31372269#31372269) that does the parsing in a safer manner.

Comment: @stribizhev: `eval`ing the user's own input is not unsafe... after all, they could also just type the code in the console.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not the regex but the eval.

```
var command = "234+234";
var result = window.eval(command); // result will be 468 so the regex will fail
var bool = re.test(result); // equals re.test(468);
```

Instead call it on the `command`

```
var command = "234+234";
var bool = re.test(command); // equals re.test("234+234");
```

Comment: I trying to evaluate the result, no the expresion. Thanks'alls